# write a command output to a file and match a string

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I'm writing below script to print the system boot time information from the windows command `systeminfo`. There look some problem here. I'm getting the output like this.

Could someone help me

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = 'sysinfo.txt';
my @cmdout = `systeminfo`;
open(my $cmd, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $cmd @cmdout;
foreach my $file (@cmdout) {
    open my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die;
    while (my $line = <$cmd>) {
        if ($line =~ m/.*System Boot.*/i) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Died at perl_sysboottime.pl line 8.
```

Comment: What is line 8?

Comment: you're opening $cmd twice. There's no error from Perl point of view but quite confusing for anyone who will have to maintain your code

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten brackets?

```
open my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die;
```

to

```
open (my $cmd, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die;
```

Comment: Parenthesis are not mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open each line given by the command systeminfo. They aren't files, they are lines of information.

A revisited version of your script could be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @cmdout = `systeminfo`;
foreach my $line (@cmdout) {
    print $line if $line =~ /System Boot/i;
}
```

or, if you want to keep data in `$filename`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = 'sysinfo.txt';
my @cmdout = `systeminfo`;
open(my $cmd, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $cmd @cmdout;
foreach my $line (@cmdout) {
    print $cmd $line if $line =~ /System Boot/i;
}
```